# Outlook 2013 single key shortcut

Tags: outlook, vsto, shortcut

I'm trying to build a Outlook 2013 plugin using VSTO , when a user press a single key (not a combination of keys) do something 
Any suggestion how to do that ?

Thanks,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

VSTO doesn't provide anything for that. You need to use Windows API to set up a keyboard hook. See [Using shortcut keys to call a function in an Office Add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/09/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi Eugene,

Thanks for your replay, I already tried that link but is not working for me

I can see the hook working with other windows but when Outlook has the focus nothing happens